# jQuery Infinite Knob/circular slider/dial input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any jQuery knob input plugin that can be fully rotated more than one and it will still increase input just like this flash calculator: http://www.health-calc.com/diet/energy-expenditure-advanced

This is how I want the dial/round slider to function: It has to be infinite knob a la the iPod clickwheel, The more you scroll the faster the value changes, and you could go on forever or until the desired value is reached. A use case for this would be as an alternative to sliders when you don't know what the the min and max values are.

This is the plugin I found but does not allow more than one rotation: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you mention can be used for infinite knobs. This mode might have been added with an update in November 2013.

It's demoed on the button of the page. Search for *iPad click wheel*:
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

This plugin also supports infinite knobs. Be aware it's published under a different license.
http://www.ohsean.net/plugins/jogdial/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one IMO:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/round-slider

It's very professional with many options. Only one issue, integration is a pain if you need to support anti-clockwise (AKA counter clockwise).

And no I didn't make it!